# number of possible chess games countable or uncountable considering games that end in check-mate and not go on forever

Tags: combinatorics, logic, recreational-mathematics, game-theory

We know that a chess game ends when a state called checkmate is reached. Considering games which end in checkmate and not considering games that go on forever, is the number of different possible chess games countable or uncountable? Could someone give me possible hints to attack the problem?

Recall a set $S$ is countable if $|S|$ $\leq |\mathbb{N}|.$

Comment: Hint: There are finitely many moves that can be made on a chessboard. The number of integers in base $N$ is countable.

Comment: The number of possible chess games is finite, thanks to the threefoold repetition rule.

Comment: Since three-times repetition and fifty moves only allow either player to claim a draw, but don't force a draw,, uncountably many endless games exist.  Put a white knight and black knight at e4 and e5.  Each player moves their knight away and back again, with a choice of six moves each time.  These games are one-one with base-six decimals, and uncountable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are finitely many possible ways to place figures on the board, one can number them [the ways] with $\mathbb N$. Then it is possible to describe any game with a unique finite (since we consider only the games that were ended) sequence of natural numbers.

Is the set $F$ of finite sequences of natural numbers countable? Yes. Try to build an injection $F\hookrightarrow\mathbb N$. It is usefully to remember about different numeral systems.

Comment: Can we simply argue that the set of all finite sequences of natural numbers is a countable union of countable sets ( i.e, each $\mathbb N^{k}$ for fixed $k \in \mathbb N$ ) and thus, countable?

Comment: Yes, that is the shortest way. And here is another beautiful solution. If you have a finite sequence $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\in\mathbb N^n$ written with base-2 you can match $a_12a_22\dots2a_n\in\mathbb N$ to it (with, for instance, base-10).